# Parsing json and getting a nullexception regardless of how many nullchecks I do

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I'm trying to parse a JSON stream that sometimes returns a null package:

```
{"package":null}
```

I've tried pretty much everything I could find to check for an null package but I'm still getting exceptions on jObjects that should work.
Here's my code

```
string json = APIRequests.RestClient.makeRequest(uri);
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken token = jObject["killID"];
        try
        {
            if (JsonExtensions.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                Kill kill = new Kill(
                    true,
                    (int)jObject.SelectToken("package.killmail.killID"),
                    (int)jObject.SelectToken("package.killmail.victim.alliance.id_str"),
                    (string)jObject.SelectToken("package.killmail.victim.alliance.name")
                    );
                return kill;
            }
            else
            {
                Kill nullKill = new Kill(false);
                return nullKill;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Kill nullKill = new Kill(false);
            Console.WriteLine(ex + jObject.ToString());
            return nullKill;

        }
```

The JsonExtensions class:

```
 public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this JToken token)
    {
        return (token == null) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.Array && !token.HasValues) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.Object && !token.HasValues) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.String && token.ToString() == String.Empty) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.Null);
    }
}
```

Exceptions occurs when I try to instantiate a 'Kill' object.
This is how 'Kill' looks:

```
 public class Kill
{
    public bool valid;
    public int killid;
    public int allianceid;
    public string alliancename;
    public Kill(bool _valid, int _killid = -1, int _allianceid = -1, string _alliancename = "null")
    {
        valid = _valid;
        killid = _killid;
        allianceid = _allianceid;
        alliancename = _alliancename;
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.EnsureValue(JToken value)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.op_Explicit(JToken value)
   at ThiccBott.ObjectParser.ParseKill(String uri) in C:\Users\user\Documents\c#\thiccbott\Utils\ThiccBott.ZkillParser.cs:line 21{
  "package": {
    "killID": 61807875,
    "killmail": {
      "solarSystem": {
        "id_str": "30045306",
        "href": "https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/solarsystems/30045306/",
        "id": 30045306,
        "name": "Hykanima"
      },
      "killID": 61807875,
      "killTime": "2017.04.24 18:39:42",............................
```

[Docs on the very simple API I'm using](https://github.com/zKillboard/RedisQ)

Comment: Surely you meant `if (!JsonExtensions.IsNullOrEmpty(token))` -- notice that your code is missing the **`!`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check that `token` is **not** null or empty.  Your code is missing the **`!`**.

Also, in the case of a *valid* response, you need to replace `token = jObject["killID"];` with `token = jObject.SelectToken("package.killID");`

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
//JToken token = jObject["killID"];
var token = jObject.SelectToken("package.killID");

if (!JsonExtensions.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
{
    Kill kill = new Kill(
        true,
        (int)jObject.SelectToken("package.killmail.killID"),
        (int)jObject.SelectToken("package.killmail.victim.alliance.id_str"),
        (string)jObject.SelectToken("package.killmail.victim.alliance.name")
        );
    return kill;
}
else
{
    Kill nullKill = new Kill(false);
    return nullKill;
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aqJEaI).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The missing '!' was a typo between writing this question and trying more stuff. The code would go into the if statement and throw an exception on the class instantiation. However, I think that changing the SelectToken jPath syntax has finally fixed the issue! Thank you.